# Spring RestTemplate deserialising generic list with wrapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics, resttemplate

Currently I have the following generic wrapper for the response of the rest service that I am consuming -

```
class Response<T> {
  private T data;
  private boolean success;
  ...
}
```

I want to use a generic Util method for consuming all types of `T data` objects that I receive from this service. The following is the Util method snippet that I currently wrote -

```
public <T> List<T> invokeServiceForList(ServiceRequestFactory factory) throws ServiceException {
        ResponseEntity<Response<List<T>>> responseEntity = null;
        List<T> data = null;
        try {
            responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(factory.getUriBuilder().toUriString(), factory.getHttpMethod(), factory.getRequestEntity(), new ParameterizedTypeReference<Response<List<T>>>() {});

            if (responseEntity.getBody() != null && !responseEntity.getBody().isSuccess()) {
                LOG.error("Response received from service with errors");
                throw new Exception("Error");
            }

            data = responseEntity.getBody().getData();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Internal service exception while connecting to service", e);
            throw new Exception("Internal Error");
        }

        return data;
    }
```

I am currently invoking the above method in the following way -

```
ServiceDelegate delegate = new ServiceDelegate(restTemplate);
List<User> users = delegate.invokeServiceForList(factory);
```

When my `T` is a simple POJO (for example a `User`), I am getting an `ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>` as the output of this method instead of `ArrayList<User>`.

Ideally, I would like the delegate method to infer the type `User` and I do not want to explicitly pass the ParameterizedTypeReference as a parameter to this method. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong over here or what else can be done?

Comment: Take `ParameterizedTypeReference` value in parameter in method to make it work like `ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>> type` and send the exact type refference when call the method

Comment: Show us how you're calling _`invokeServiceForList(ServiceRequestFactory)`_ please? TIA.

Comment: @deduper 
```ServiceDelegate delegate = new ServiceDelegate(restTemplate);
    List<User> users = delegate.invokeServiceForList(factory);```
Here `ServiceDelegate` contains the `invokeServiceForList` method

Comment: Thank you Sir. Do you have a requirement to change the signature of _`ServiceDelegate.invokeServiceForList(ServiceRequestFactory)`_?

Comment: @deduper I can, if needed. But I would prefer NOT to add the ParameterizedTypeReference as a parameter as suggested by Rono . Any other alternate approach which can directly infer the type of the object will be really helpful for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: „*I would prefer NOT to add the ParameterizedTypeReference as a parameter as suggested by Rono*“ — Thank you Vinay Nikhil. — „*...Any other alternate approach which can directly infer the type of the object will be really helpful for me...*“ —  I understand that to mean that you have already tried all three (*so far*) proposed solutions? And none of them solved your problem? Have I understood you correctly? Also, please post the error messages you get with the solution that I proposed? If you prefer to discuss in a private chat, let me know. TIA.

Comment: I've thrown my hands up and withdrawn my answer. This issue is practically impossible to resolve without knowing:  (***1***) The ***full*** implementation of _`class Response<T>{...}`_.  (***2***) Either a snippet of code from the RESTful endpoint that shows how it constructs and returns its response. (***3***) And/or a snippet of the response JSON from a call to the RESTful endpoint. And (***4***) Details of how you're calling _`ServiceDelegate.invokeServiceForList(ServiceRequestFactory)`_. I'm still curious to learn the solution though. So please keep us posted if you solve it yourself? TIA.

Comment: @deduper it works when I pass the `ParameterizedTypeReference` as a parameter to my `ServiceDelegate.invokeServiceForList` as proposed by Rono. But as mentioned I was looking for something that doesn't explicitly take it as a parameter and infers it using generics

Comment: „*...it works when I pass the `ParameterizedTypeReference` as a parameter...*“ — Thanks VinayNikhil. That's helpful to know. — „*as mentioned I was looking for something that doesn't explicitly take it as a parameter and infers it using generics*“ — As *I* mentioned, what would be even more helpful to people trying to help you find what you're looking for, is you editing your question with *at least some* (*ideally, **all***) of the 4 things I requested. If that's too much code to put in SO, then a link to git repo with a *small* reproducer might be even ***more*** helpful still. TIA.

Comment: @deduper I have updated the description with more details about the question. I hope this helps

Comment: Thx Vinay. How would you model the _`data`_ in your API call as, say, RAML? Or Swagger/OpenAPI docs? Or JSON Schema? Here are 4 JSON Schemas (***1***) [*As an array*](https://app.quicktype.io?share=sJz29UK7o1B3dQW4wIzV) (***2***) [*An object*](https://app.quicktype.io?share=MXhvbjtg9EDesVUv8sXD) (***3***) [*An object with arrays*](https://app.quicktype.io?share=3VvwiToqTqDEV4Atzv6H) (***4***) [*A number*](https://app.quicktype.io?share=bBX4BoYBFd06buVlZJd1). With your design, _`data`_ could be ***any*** type. It seems confused. How are your consumers going to verify that the response is valid?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove generic in the diamond from:

```
 new ParameterizedTypeReference<Response<List<T>>>() {}
```

to:

```
new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {}
```

after that, I would check variable responseEntity in debug mode and see what is inside.
Now you will be able to extract correctly data which you need from responseEntity.

Comment: Thanks Sir. [*The docs for `ParameterizedTypeReference<T>` say*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ParameterizedTypeReference.html): „*In order to capture the generic type and retain it at runtime, you need to create a subclass (ideally as anonymous inline class) as follows:
`ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>> typeRef = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {};)`*“. Two questions for you. Please?: (***Q1***) What is the type argument that fills in _`T`_ in your example? (***Q2***) Why should OP not do what the docs advise?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is, take `ParameterizedTypeReference` value in the parameter in method like `ParameterizedTypeReference<Response<List<T>>>` type and send the exact type reference when calling the method

Add parameter in the method

```
public <T> List<T> invokeServiceForList(ServiceRequestFactory factory,
            ParameterizedTypeReference<Response<List<T>>> type) throws ServiceException {
    ...
    restTemplate.exchange(factory.getUriBuilder().toUriString(), factory.getHttpMethod(), factory.getRequestEntity(), type);
    ...
}
```

And call like this

```
List<User> users = delegate.invokeServiceForList(factory, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Response<List<User>>>() {});
```

Comment: Thank you Rono. — „_Add parameter in the method `public <T> List<T> invokeServiceForList(ServiceRequestFactory factory, ParameterizedTypeReference<Response<List<T>>> type)`_“ — Can you help me understand why @VinayNikhil needs to change his method signature? TIA.

Comment: @deduper because when initializing `ServiceDelegate` doesn't specify the generic parameter, so there is no way to know what is `T` inside the method. As I don't know about the full class I give a way to fix with minimal information.

Comment: „*...because when initializing ServiceDelegate doesn't specify the generic parameter, so there is no way to know what is T inside the method...*“ — Thank you Rono. @VinayNikhil wrote in a comment that his _`ServiceDelegate.invokeServiceForList(ServiceRequestFactory)`_ method would be called like: _`List<User> users = delegate.invokeServiceForList(factory);`_. So why wouldn't _`T`_ be inferred from the method invocation assignment to _`List<User> users`_? TIA.

Comment: @deduper How do you know which java version OP used ?

Comment: „*...How do you know which java version OP used ?...*“ — I don't know what version of Java @VinayNikhil used. Can you help me understand why the version matters to his question, to your answer and to method invocation return type inference? TIA.

Comment: @Rono This way works. But as you mentioned, this seems to be a workaround. Is there any possibility to infer the type directly instead of explicitly passing it?

Comment: @VinayNikhil You can wait till any good solution come or start a bounty.

Comment: @Rono how do I do that?